# iOS: While archiving getting linker error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, watchkit, xmppframework

I have iOS app, i m able to run successfully in iPhone, but i m trying to archiving. I m getting 2 errors
1.Invalid bitcode signature (As per some other posts i kept Enable Bitcode = NO)
2.linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I followed the solution given some other experts who got the same issue, but i m unable to fix my issue based on their suggestions.
My project has pod installed for many frameworks and Libraries also My project having watch extension as well.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Snapshot which i m getting errors in my XCode]

Comment: Use the xcworkspace to build instead of the xcproject?

This usually happens when using Cocoapods and you are building from the xcproject which doesn't know about the cocoapod libraries.

Comment: @NisarAhmad : Thanks for your earlier response, I m working on **xcWorkspace** only. If you have any further suggestions. please let me know.